# Rigorously deriving the solution of the differential equations system $\frac{d}{dt}\mathbf{y}(t) = \mathbf{A} y(t)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, matrix-exponential

The unique solution of the linear ordinary differential equation system $$\frac{d}{dt}\mathbf{y}(t) = \mathbf{A} \mathbf {y}(t)$$ is supposedly given by $$\mathbf{y}(t) = (\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k!}(\mathbf{A}t)^k)\mathbf{y}(0)$$ where $\mathbf{A}$ is a real or complex matrix (cf. [linear differential equations system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_exponential#Linear_differential_equation_systems)).

How to *derive* this rigorously (and not just *prove* it by plugging it in the original differential equation)?

Comment: You mean to exclude the solution path of looking at $y(t)=e^{At}c(t)$ and then finding $c'(t)=0$?

Comment: I'm kind of trying to motivate the fact that $e^{\mathbf A} = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{\mathbf{A}^k}{k!}$ from here. Most textbooks say that the solution is $e^{\mathbf A t}\mathbf y(0)$ and leave it there without giving any actual derivation. Even Wikipedia does the same. I'm not sure which method you're talking about exactly, but if you could give me a reference I'll look it up.

Comment: You can just insert a power series with undetermined coefficients, which quickly leads to the exponential series. Then confirm the convergence with matrix coefficients and that the derivative of the power series is as expected.

Comment: @LutzLehmann Sounds nice. Do you know of a textbook that does it that way? Or could you write it as an answer? I'd like to read the whole derivation in detail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the given equation,

$$\frac{d^2}{dt^2}\mathbf y(t)=\frac{d}{dt}\mathbf A\mathbf y(t)=\mathbf A\frac{d}{dt}\mathbf y(t)=\mathbf A^2\mathbf y(t)$$

and by induction $$\frac{d^n}{dt^n}\mathbf y(t)=\mathbf A^n\mathbf y(t).$$

Then by a simple application of Taylor around $t=0$,

$$\mathbf y(t)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left.\frac{d^n}{dt^n}\mathbf y(t)\right|_{t=0}\frac{t^n}{n!}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\mathbf A^n\mathbf y(0)\frac{t^n}{n!}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(\mathbf At)^n}{n!}\mathbf y(0).$$

---

Uniqueness can probably be established using the [Picard-Lindelöf theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picard-Lindel%C3%B6f_theorem).

Comment: It is easy to verify that the given is a solution of the system of linear ODE. However, it seems that we still need to show that it is UNIQUE.

Comment: This is really nice (and I'll probably mark it as the accepted answer in a while)! Do you know of a textbook that shows this approach? (And yes, the uniqueness part is still left like Danny says.)

Comment: @S.D.: no but this seems obvious, doesn't it ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust Well, it wasn't obvious before I read your answer. :) It'd be nice if textbooks explained it this way, as otherwise many students find matrix exponentials confusing.

Comment: @S.D.: I mean that the steps of the proof seem obvious as they rely on a known theorem (of course you have to check the conditions of applicability of Taylor, and the expression of the remainder better be established).